# Dimension of a cuboid from coordinates in a NumPy array

Tags: python, math

I have an array of 3D coordinates representing a cuboid and its projection in 2D:

```
"cuboid": [
    [ 16.793300628662109, 12.848400115966797, 96.942703247070313 ],
    [ 26.579500198364258, 6.4942998886108398, 97.793800354003906 ],
    [ 24.501899719238281, 4.3057999610900879, 105.34329986572266 ],
    [ 14.715700149536133, 10.659799575805664, 104.49220275878906 ],
    [ 12.280900001525879, 5.444699764251709, 93.554603576660156 ],
    [ 22.067100524902344, -0.90930002927780151, 94.405799865722656 ],
    [ 19.989500045776367, -3.0978999137878418, 101.95529937744141 ],
    [ 10.203300476074219, 3.2562000751495361, 101.10420227050781 ]
],
"projected_cuboid": [
    [ 613.068115234375, 371.80960083007813 ],
    [ 688.7794189453125, 321.01361083984375 ],
    [ 658.66741943359375, 301.3988037109375 ],
    [ 588.180908203125, 348.36520385742188 ],
    [ 580.83660888671875, 314.70660400390625 ],
    [ 659.55560302734375, 262.602294921875 ],
    [ 630.6068115234375, 246.66099548339844 ],
    [ 557.5220947265625, 294.74038696289063 ]
]
```

Is there a way to get the dimension (height, width, and length) of the cuboid by just having those values?

Comment: Don't see how this is DL or PyTorch related.

Comment: I’ve set pytorch because we also do matrix manipulation in pytorch

Comment: This is question is probably better suited to the [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).